# Deploy ember application in Bluemix

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ibm-cloud, ember-cli

I am trying to deploy an existing ember-nodejs application into bluemix environment. I tried the following steps.

```
bluemix api https://api.ng.bluemix.net

bluemix login -u username -o org_name -s space_name

cf push app_name
```

I also tried the above command with an [ember build pack](https://github.com/tonycoco/heroku-buildpack-ember-cli) from the list of
compatible [CF build packs](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-docs-contrib/wiki/Buildpacks)

```
cf push app_name -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-docs-contrib/wiki/Buildpacks
```

Uploading is successful, but the application doesnt start up. Is there a recommended way of deploying ember-node js application?

**Update**

It was a memory issue. I removed the other running apps and tried the cf push command again. The node modules got installed and the application also started without any fuss.

Comment: Can you include the cf push output to help us understand what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the user, this was actually a memory issue. Once he stopped the other running apps, his node modules were installed and the application started without any further errors. There are no issues specific to deploying ember-nodejs applications in the Bluemix environment.